# Directive #include did not contain a 'file' or 'virtual' attribute

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, ssi

Не могу найти ответ, я пытаюсь оптимизировать сборку Gulp для своих нужд. Столкнулся с такой ошибкой, мне непонятно как её побороть, вроде бы все понятно - как устанавливать Browsersync-ssi, как подключать. Вот мой код:
Подключение модулей

```
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(); // Сервер
const bssi = require('browsersync-ssi');
const ssi = require('ssi');
```

И сам сервер:

```
function browsersync() { // Сервер
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app/', 
            port: 5000,
            middleware: bssi({ 
                 baseDir: 'app/', 
                 ext: '.html' 
            })
        },
        notify: false, 
        online: true
    })
}
```

в результате сервер при старте выдает такую ошибку:
Directive #include did not contain a 'file' or 'virtual' attribute
и не отрисовывает страничку и ничего не подключает, пробовал разные варианты подключений - бесполезно

И стандартное подключение:

```
<!--#include virtuat="/inc/header.html" -->
```

Пробовал обновлять модули но это тоже не помогло